# add_subplot()+groupby()+buy and sell signals plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Unfortunately, I could not plot the short and long signals to each group in groupby.
Please help me:

```
grouped = df4.groupby('T')
for name, group in grouped:
    df12=df4.C[df4.diffpos== 1.0]
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, label=name)
    group.plot(y=['C'],ax=ax1, color='r', lw=2.,figsize=(10,10))
    ax1.plot(df12,'^', markersize=10, color='m',label='Buy')
    ax.plot(df4.C[df4.diffpos== -1.0], 'v', markersize=10, color='k',label='Sell')
    plt.legend(loc = 'best')
    plt.title(name)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your question and code and explanation is incomplete and unclear. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please, share `df4` (at least a representative sample, 10 rows roughly are enough typically) and explain better what are "short" and "long" signals.